# Filter updated scope with directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Here is how I render posts. I want them to be searchable by entering keyword text into input, so I use `filter: searchText`

```
 <input ng-model="searchText"> 

 <div ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: searchText">
   <a>Follow post</a
 </div>
```

My posts JSON (extracted to the minimum) looks like that:

```
{
    "follow": false,
    "title": "Post title"
    "body": "Post description"

}
```

By default all posts, have follow:false. Users can easily click on "Follow post" link to follow/unfollow that post. I do this with the following code:

```
  $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.post.follow = true;
  })
```

I have navigation, where user can see All posts or only posts that he followed.

```
<a>Show all</a>
<a>Follow list</a>
```

I am trying to figure out how to accomplish this logic. I think I should use some complex filer logic inside custom directive, but cant figure out where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can create filter function:

```
$scope.filterPosts = function(post) {
    return post.title.indexOf($scope.searchText) >= 0 || post.body.indexOf($scope.searchText) >= 0;
}
```

and then use it to filter posts list like this

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: filterPosts">
    ...
</div>
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/bwnn39ua/

Comment: or you can create custom filter - https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09 . updated example inluding custom filter - https://jsfiddle.net/bwnn39ua/1/